# PHP secure login form with SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server, forms

It's "day two" of my php experiments, and I'm trying to put together a secure login form with php / MS SQL (sqlsrv).

Looked at a number of examples, and they all pretty much reference mysql, which doesn't really apply to my needs.

Also, just as an fyi (before someone says, why aren't you using PDO), I've had zero luck getting PDO to run in my local environment, (php 7.2) so I've been sticking to sqlsrv type of commands.

Here's what I've attempted to create so far:

**data.php page**

```
class getUsers {
    function get_all_users() {
        global $conn;
        $dbUsers = [];

        $sql = "SELECT user_name, user_password FROM users";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql) or die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($dbUsers, $row);
        }

        return $dbUsers;
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    }
}
```

First thing right off the bat, I know is not an optimal way to do this, I should probably just be retrieving one record, not all records, but I'm using the method that I gleamed from another SO post.

**login.php page**

```
<?php
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}

include_once("../includes/connection.php");
include_once("../includes/data.php");

$udata = new getUsers();
$udatas = $udata->get_all_users();
$userlist = array_column($udatas, null, 'user_name');

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    //go to logged in page.
    echo "session state = logged in";

} else {
    //display login
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
            $error = 'All fields are required';

        } else if (isset($userlist[$username], $userlist[$password])) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            echo "logged in, should only display when logged in.";
            //header('Location: cp-logged-in.php');

        } else {
            $error = "Invalid user information";
        }
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="grid-header">
    <?php include("../includes/header.php"); ?>
</div>

<div class="grid-login">
    <?php include("cp-login.php") ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lots of issues with this:

1) Since I don't have the checking the input against the database part correct, it won't actually log in.

2) There's **zero** security implimented on this, and from what I've gleaned on SO, at the very least, I should be doing some sort of hashtag / salting of pw's, and perhaps some other stuff to protect against SQL injections.

So to the first issue, I'm quite certain there's a more efficient way to check the un/pw against the database. Ideally, I'd like to keep the login function in a separate file, (to keep it cleaner) but perhaps that would make things more difficult? (as it would require passing the username/password variables back and forth between the two php pages).

And to the second issue, in looking at a couple of security articles, would blowfish or php's native password_hash() be the way to go? As I understand it, md5 isn't all that secure.

In thinking about future improvements, this may be a bigger question, but would a smarter approach be to not store passwords in the database at all, and somehow include a random password generator type of function? Maybe that's too much to tackle right off the bat?

thanks! :)